# Disable direct access to application via Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a small local (internal to organisation) browser application running on Tomcat.  I have inherited an application (also for internal organisation use only) running under PHP server which I have been asked to get running on the same box.  I decided the best thing was to get both Tomcat and PHP running under Apache Web Server.  Initially I thought this was essential although I now thing as long as I had left them running with different ports this was unnecessary (?).

I have got my Tomcat app running through Apache using the proxy_http_module.  I was wondering if there is an easy way to stop direct access to the application via tomcat?

So for example in Tomcat the app is set to run as

http://localserver:1234/superapp

using the virtual host configuration apache allows access as

http://localserver/superapp

presumably this means if I now go in as http://localserver:1234/superapp I am bypassing apache web server ?  Assuming (bold assumption) that I have not misunderstood the mechanism, is there a simple way to stop access directly via tomcat (http://localserver:1234/superapp).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using the proxy_ajp instead of proxy_http. But you can also use the RemoteAddrValve to define restrictions based on IP address:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
        allow="127\.0\.0\.1"/>
    ...
</Engine>
```

Comment: This looks about right assuming it still allows access forwarded from Apache (presumably this is done in the config).  Anyway I'll try and get my head around the documentation.  Thanks.